# Unable to see multiple view in magento

Tags: magento

I have 4 store view in my magento 1.English 2.French 3.German 4.Spanish.all store view are enable but i am unable to see them on front end to change from one view to another view.

Any suggestion to sort out this issue ?

Comment: This may Help you  http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

Comment: Try to create first store than assign store view.After that you will able to see on front.

Comment: Ok I did this but problem was something else

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution I have to add this code
 "getChildHtml('store_language') ?>"   in header.phptml